# How to jar all *.class in all sub folders recursively?

Tags: java, jar

"main" method is in Application\Program.class

[image: Project Structure]

I can generate the jar file by:

```
jar cvfe PwdGen.jar Application.Program Application\*.class Info\*.class
```

But if I have more directory with more class, I have to add more "direcotory\*.class" attach to the back of command.

Is there a simple way to include all (include sub folders) *.class recursively once for all?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the below command to create a jar for multiple directories.

```
 jar cvfe pwd.jar */*.class
```

Comment: I tried, it's respone "no such file or directory".

Comment: It could be that you don't have a .class file there.